# Re-installing corrupted TeX Live binaries

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

I somehow corrupted my texlive binaries and started to get `cannot execute binary file` errors. I want to reinstall only the binaries so I don't have to install all 7Gb of texlive again. When I run `perl install-tl` from the installation directory, it detects the current installation and I think goes into update mode. How can I reinstall all the binaries to an existing installation?

Comment: You could try building from source (https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Source/) and then copy the generated binaries to the correct location manually. But a full automatic reinstall is of course easier so maybe that would still be the preferred solution, even if it would take some time to download and install everything. And it would be advised to find out how the binaries got corrupted in the first place, this is not something that would normally happen so you should find out what the problem is to prevent it happening again.

Comment: @Marijn I suspect that I corrupted them by running a disk level restoration from a Windows machine for irrelevant reasons, shortly after installing texlive. Not sure if that is possible, but I cannot see any other cause. And yes, after several attempts, I gave up and decided to reinstall the entire texlive.